# Is there a way to have an iframe in fullscreen?

Tags: html, css, iframe, fullscreen

I want to put an iframe onto my page with a another div over top of the iframe to go back to a specific page, however, I cannot seem to get the iframe to go full screen (height:100% and width: 100%). Is there any work around to get the iframe in full screen?

I have already tried setting the height to window height using jquery, however, its not working.

```
<style>    
    iframe {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
    }

    .goback {
      width:100%;
      background-color:transparent;
      transition:.5s;
      position: absolute;
      z-index:3;
    }

    .goback img {
      padding:5px;
    }

    .goback:hover {
      background-color:white;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="goback">

        <img src="../../assets/goback.png" alt="goback" height="50px" width="50px" />

    </div>

    <iframe src="https://music.youtube.com/"></iframe>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Viewport width and height instead of percentages

```
iframe {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your css (Set body margin to 0, position iframe absolute and set the border to 0)

Example:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
 width:100%; height:100vh;
```

of iframe.